# What is tattvavada?

Tags: dvaita

Is it a concept from Dvaita? Or is it another name for the whole of Madhwa's Dvaita philosophy? Is it supposed to be the true or real state or truth or reality?

Comment: It is the nom de plumegiven by sri vadiraja swamigal for entire gamut Madhva philosophy